# Iterate over strings in assembly (NASM)

Tags: string, memory, assembly, nasm, memory-address

I am trying to count the length of the string argv[1] in NASM assembly language. I think I'm on the right track. I have moved the address of argv[1] to register eax and now I want to move through it byte by byte and compare to the null string terminator.

Everytime I run the code it segfaults on the null comparison. Am I not getting the memory indexing correct?

*Disclaimer: This is a small part of a large homework assignment.

```
segment .bss

N: resd 1                 ;counter for size of argv[1]

segment .text
  global asm_main

asm_main:
  enter 0,0               ;setup
  pusha                   ;save all registers

  mov eax, dword [ebp+8]  ;argc to eax

  mov ebx, dword [ebp+12] ; address of argv to ebx
  mov eax, dword [ebx+4]  ; address of argv[1] to eax

  mov [N], dword 0        ; N = 0 

  .loop:

    add eax, [N]          ; advance index by N
    cmp eax, dword 0      ; check for end of string
    je .endloop           ; break out of the loop if we're done


    add [N], dword 1      ; N++    

    jmp .loop             ; loop back for next char

  .endloop:

popa
mov eax, 0
leave
ret
```

Comment: Which instruction does it actually segfault on?  `add eax, [N]` reads from a fixed address, so if it doesn't segfault the first time, it shouldn't ever segfault.  Use a debugger to single-step and see what's in regs/mem when you fault.

Comment: The most obvious problem here is that you never read from the string, you just increment a pointer and compare it against zero.  (And you increment eax geometrically, because `[N]` increases linearly.)

Comment: It dies on the cmp line. You're right, the line I have above compares an address (hopefully the address of the character) with an expected value, instead of the character itself. Should I have cmp [eax], dword 0?

Comment: It can't segfault on `cmp` because it has no memory operands.  That makes no sense.  Yes,  `cmp dword  [eax], 0` is closer to correct, but there's still a ton of stuff wrong with your loop.  Hint, what size are the elements in a string?  Hint, not dwords.

Comment: A string would be [byte][byte][byte]...[null]. So no a dword, but a byte. EAX should hold the address to the byte. [EAX] should be the byte in question. cmp [eax], byte 0?

Comment: Yup.  That's right once you fix the pointer-increment part of the loop.

Comment: Oh. I'm incrementing by 1, which is too small. I should be incrementing by 4 to move along by a full byte. I need to multiply N by 4 before adding to eax.

Comment: /facepalm.  No.  x86 is a byte-addressable architecture, where two adjacent bytes differ in address by 1.  Use a debugger and watch EAX.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks for your time and patience. I appreciate you trying to hint me along.

Comment: @PeterCordes I just /facepalmed myself when I saw it on the debugger. Fixing it up now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few hints and the help of gdb, the loop now looks like this:

```
  mov [N], dword 0        ; N = 0 

  .loop:

    cmp [eax], byte 0     ; check for end of string
    je .endloop    

    add eax, dword 1      ; advance index by 1 byte
    add [N], dword 1      ; N++    

    jmp .loop             

  .endloop:
```

Using N to increment the index was silly. I needed to increment by 1.

Comment: Note that you don't need a separate counter.  You can just do `sub eax, start_of_string` after the loop.  (And never keep your loop counters in memory if you can avoid it.  It's really slow.  Your code will run almost exactly 6 times slower on most Intel CPUs than if you'd kept N in a register (or avoided it entirely), because it puts a store/reload round trip into a loop-carried dependency chain, and store-forwarding latency is 5 cycles on Intel SnB-family CPUs.).

Comment: While I appreciate you are aware of size of data you use, JFYI: the `add eax, dword 1` doesn't need the size specifier, as the `eax` on one side enforces 32b size context of the instruction. So in such case `add eax,1` is enough. The one below `add [N], dword 1` is correct, that one needs size specifier at least on one side, as without it it's ambiguous, it would make sense also with `byte` or `word`, if `N` would be only byte/word. And to do +-1 the x86 has dedicated opcodes `inc` and `dec`, saves typing of that `,1`. Not sure why I really like those two. :)