# How to traverse a string in assembly until I reach null? (strlen loop)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, att, strlen

Right now I'm just figuring out how to even traverse a string. If the code doesn't make sense, it's because I've interpreted some information wrong. At the worst, I don't really know what I'm doing.

```
strlen:

pushq %rbx
movq %rsi, %rbx


loop:
    cmp $0x00, (%rdi, %rbx)
    je end
    inc %rbx
    jmp loop

end:
    movq %rbx, %rax
    popq %rbx
    ret
```

---

PS: There's a reason my title looks like an old man 2nd time on his computer trying to search "how to go to google.com"    Superrrr noob here trying to learn a little bit of assembly. I'm trying to implement strlen function for myself.

Comment: Check this out it will help you understand https://stackoverflow.com/a/40647017/10927635

Comment: cmp with an immediate operand requires the immediate to be the first (source) operand.  Also, you can just use RDI as the pointer in the loop, or pick some call-clobbered register so you don't have to save/restore RBX.

Comment: So is using %rbx correct in this case? What about using %ebx? I know it's just a convention in a sense but just for clarity.

Comment: [Why does rax and rdi work the same in this situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54867399) has a working strlen in NASM syntax.  It's not "magic", just increment a pointer.  And yes, RBX is fine with `inc %rbx`, but using RAX would let you do the same thing without without having to save/restore RBX.  And no, you don't want to use 32-bit registers for pointers.

Comment: When I inc %rbx, am I incrementing by 1 byte? So therefore if I do cmp $0x00, (%rdi, % rbx), it should compare the pointer to null, correct? From what I understand, in att  (%rdi, %rbx) is the same thing as (rdi + rbx).

Comment: RDI and RBX both hold pointers.  Adding them together doesn't make a valid address!  I didn't find any SO Q&As with a strlen implementation that didn't suck in some major way (e.g. 2 branches inside the loop like this one) so I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just `inc %rbx` to increment the pointer value.  `(%rbx)` dereferences that register, using its value as a memory address.  On x86, every byte has its own address (this property is called "byte addressable"), and addresses are just integers that fit in a register.

The characters in an ASCII string are all 1 byte wide so incrementing a pointer by 1 moves to the next character in an ASCII string.  (This isn't true in the general case of UTF-8 with characters outside the 1..127 range of codepoints, but ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.)

---

Terminology: ASCII code `0` is called NUL (one L), not NULL.  In C, NULL is a pointer concept.  C-style implicit-length strings can be described as 0-terminated or NUL-terminated, but "null-terminated" is misusing the terminology.

---

You should pick a different register (one that's call-clobbered) so you don't need to push/pop it around your function.  Your code doesn't *make* any function calls, so there's no need to keep your induction variable in a call-preserved register.

I didn't find a *good* simple example in other SO Q&As.  They either have 2 branches inside the loop (including one unconditional jmp) like the one I linked in comments, or they waste instructions incrementing a pointer *and* a counter.  Using an indexed addressing mode inside the loop is not terrible, but is less efficient on some CPUs so I'd still recommend doing a pointer increment -> subtract end-start after the loop.

**This is how I'd write a minimal strlen that only checks 1 byte at a time (slow and simple)**.  I kept the loop itself small, and this is IMO a reasonable example of a good way of writing loops in general.  Often keeping your code compact makes it easier to understand a function in asm.  (Give it a different name than `strlen` so you can test it without needing `gcc -fno-builtin-strlen` or whatever.)

```
.globl simple_strlen
simple_strlen:
    lea     -1(%rdi), %rax     # p = start-1 to counteract the first inc
 .Lloop:                       # do {
    inc     %rax                  # ++p
    cmpb    $0, (%rax)
    jne     .Lloop             # }while(*p != 0);
                           # RAX points at the terminating 0 byte = one-past-end of the real data
    sub     %rdi, %rax     # return length = end - start
    ret
```

The return value of `strlen` is the array index of the `0` byte = length of the data *not* including the terminator.

If you were inlining this manually (because it's just a 3-instruction loop), you'd often just want a pointer to the 0 terminator so you wouldn't bother with the sub crap, just use RAX at the end of the loop.

Avoiding the offsetting LEA/INC instructions before the first load (which cost 2 cycles of latency before the first cmp) could be done by peeling the first iteration, or with a `jmp` to enter the loop at the cmp/jne, after the inc.  [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump).

Incrementing the pointer with LEA between cmp/jcc (like `cmp` ; `lea 1(%rax), %rax` ; `jne`) could be worse because it defeats macro-fusion of cmp/jcc into a single uop.  (Actually, macro-fusion of `cmp $imm, (%reg)` / jcc doesn't happen on Intel CPUs like Skylake anyway.  `cmp` micro-fuses the memory operand, though.  Maybe AMD fuses the cmp/jcc.)  Also, you'd leave the loop with RAX 1 higher than you want.

So it would be just as efficient (on Intel Sandybridge-family) to `movzx` (aka `movzbl`) load and zero-extend a byte into `%ecx`, and `test %ecx, %ecx` / `jnz` as the loop condition.  But larger code-size.

---

Most CPUs will run my loop at 1 iteration per clock cycle.  We could maybe get close to 2 bytes per cycle (while still only checking each byte separately) with some loop unrolling.

**Checking 1 byte at a time is about 16x slower for large strings than we could go with SSE2.**  If you aren't aiming for minimal code size and simplicity, see [Why is this code 6.5x slower with optimizations enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563598/why-is-this-code-6-5x-slower-with-optimizations-enabled/55589634#55589634) for a simple SSE2 strlen that uses an XMM register.  SSE2 is baseline for x86-64 so you should always use it when it gives a speedup, for stuff that's worth writing by hand in asm.

---

**Re: your updated question** with a buggy port of the implementation from [Why does rax and rdi work the same in this situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867399/why-does-rax-and-rdi-work-the-same-in-this-situation)

RDI and RBX both hold pointers.  Adding them together doesn't make a valid address!  In the code you were trying to port, RCX (the index) is initialized to zero before the loop.  But instead of `xor %ebx, %ebx`, you did `mov %rdi, %rbx`.  Use a debugger to examine register values while you single-step your code.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation made sense.